# How to use Meteor method in Meteor + Ionic app

Tags: javascript, angular, meteor, ionic-framework, angular-meteor

I had developed the web app in the Meteor. Now I want to create a *Meteor* + *Ionic* app. So, I want to use the pre-existing *Meteor* methods in my *Ionic* app. I don't want to create the same method again for a mobile app. How can we solve this?
Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to use the Ionic CLI/Angular CLI or the Meteor CLI?  all of those options are possible now

Comment: i have created a web app using meteor + angular. Next i want to create a ionic app. So i want to know which approach is batter...
1- create separate meteor + ionic app and use meteor web app api
2- create ionic app inside meteor web app and use meteor app api
And also want to know how to use meteor web app method in ionic app for re usability..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

can connect you through api rest
http://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html
the front-end with angular-ionic and backend with meteor

Comment: Is it batter to create separate mobile app or create with web app